# Table Not Found with Hibernate and HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

We're using hibernate entitymanager to map our entities through JPA. And we are using HSQLDB in-memory database for unit testing. Everything was fine until a recent refactor to the model started causing the following error:

```
17:55:48.516 [main] WARN  o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -22, SQLState: S0002
17:55:48.517 [main] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Table not found in statement
```

I can't post the SQL in question, but can anyone give me pointers as to the possible causes of the above error? especially since I know the code was working before. It seems like hibernate is generating invalid sqls because of the refactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, is the table actually there? Enable SQL output for Hibernate and check it against the actual database schema.

Your refactoring may have been botched (entity and table were renamed; named query was not updated).

Or you may have an older class(es) somewhere in classpath causing wrong annotations to be read.

Comment: Turns out an entity was named to a reserved word, causing table creation to fail.

Comment: reserved word - I had the same problem !

Answer (score 3):

This could also indicate a mismatch between the JDBC driver and the Hibernate dialect.

We got this when the JDBC driver connection was HSQLDB and the Hibernate dialect was org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect.

The corresponding exception message:
[ERROR]: could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [ select sequence_name from all_sequences]

Comment: Hibernate needs to have set a SQL Dialect. It needs to match the database vendor configured in the jdbc uri.

Example of how to configurate Hibernate session-factory to use a certain SQL dialect can be found here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration

Answer (score 2):

We were also getting the same exception. It turns out the property **hibernate.dialect** was set as org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect with H2 data base serving as a datasource. The solution is to remove hibernate.dialect and do not use any value. Hibernate have the capability to auto detect dialect based metadata retrieved from datasource configuration 
 **For more information on how hibernate auto-detects dialect**
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/portability.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, in my case I had something like this in the entity

@Column(name = "AVAIL_TARGET_PERCENT", columnDefinition = "number(5,2)", nullable = false)

Just avoid the columnDefinition (take it out!) and you should be fine. I did that, and the problem was fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use dependency

```
groupId org.hsqldb
```

instead of

```
groupId hsqldb
```

in your pom.xml or gradle. Check out https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=hsqldb